# pytest raise PytestUnknownMarkWarning for pytest.mark.optionalhook in conftest

Tags: python, pytest

In pytest files, I have a main.py for test entrance and have such code in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    # my code
```

and in another py file, I use os.system to call the main.py above

```
os.system('python main.py')
```

but there's warning message like:

```
PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.optionalhook
```

I'm curious, `pytest.mark.optionalhook` is provided by pytest structure. Why is there still warning?

Comment: have you checked this https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/mark.html#registering-marks ?
You need to register the marker.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like U R using a mark rather than a hook param. I'd suggest that you're using this way:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(optionalhook=True)
def pytest_your_hook(...): ...
```